# Error caused by libgd-dev when installing software

Tags: compiling

I tried to install a plotting software. It passed "./configure" but it failed on "make & make install". See below:

```
htan@HT:~/grads-2.2.1$ sudo make
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/htan/grads-2.2.1/src'
make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/htan/grads-2.2.1/src'
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I. -I..//include   -g -O2 -rdynamic -c -o libgxpGD_la-gxprintGD.lo `test -f 'gxprintGD.c' || echo './'`gxprintGD.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I..//include -g -O2 -rdynamic -c gxprintGD.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libgxpGD_la-gxprintGD.o
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I. -I..//include   -g -O2 -rdynamic -c -o libgxpGD_la-gxGD.lo `test -f 'gxGD.c' || echo './'`gxGD.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I..//include -g -O2 -rdynamic -c gxGD.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libgxpGD_la-gxGD.o
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -rdynamic -version-info 1:0:1  -o libgxpGD.la -rpath /home/htan/grads-2.2.1/lib libgxpGD_la-gxprintGD.lo libgxpGD_la-gxGD.lo -L..//lib   -L/usr/local/lib -lgd -lm
**../libtool: line 6000: cd: ..//lib: No such file or directory
libtool: link: cannot determine absolute directory name of `..//lib'
Makefile:711: recipe for target 'libgxpGD.la' failed**
make[2]: *** [libgxpGD.la] Error 1**
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/htan/grads-2.2.1/src'
Makefile:610: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/htan/grads-2.2.1/src'
Makefile:458: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I feel like this issue is related to libgd. I have installed GD by myself, and I can see gdlib-config in `/usr/local/bi`n. I also tried using root account, but it showed the same error. The line 6000 in configure file shows `# Regexp to match symbols that can be accessed directly from C. sympat='\([_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*\)'`

Answer (score 0):

So far as I can tell, the error is not related to the location of gdlib.

The relevant line is actually line 6000 of the `libtool` script:

```
6000           absdir=`cd "$dir" && pwd`
```

At some point in the link phase, `dir` is being set to the value of the configure-time variable `SUPPLIBS`, which according to `./configure --help | less -N` is supposed to be

```
134   SUPPLIBS    Custom path (must be absolute) to a GrADS supplib distribution
```

By default, this is set as `SUPPLIBS='$(top_builddir)/'`, so the libtool script called from the `src` subdirectory ends up trying to `cd` to `../lib` - which does not exist in the unpacked tarball.

So, either set `SUPPLIBS` to the path to your actual GrADS supplib distribution (if you have one)

```
./configure SUPPLIBS=/path/to/GrADS/supplib
```

or alternatively create an empty `lib` directory at the top level of the `grads-2.2.1` build tree so that `cd ..//lib` does not fail:

```
./configure
mkdir ./lib
make
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, appreciate someone could help me during the weekend! Your answer works except for one small correction which is that I used ./configure SUPPLIBS=/path/to/GrADS/supplib/lib.  Thanks again!